# Extract Data from DF into a new DF

Tags: python, dataframe, append

[image]

I am not confident you can see the image.  I am a student, last class before graduation, thought python would be fun.  Stuck on an issue.

I have a dataframe called final_hgun_frame_raw that successfully lists every state plus DC, in alphabetical order.  THere is an index column at starts at 0 - 51.  The column headings are STATE, 2010,2011...2019.

The table shows, for example, that index 0 is AL and under column 2010 there is a value 2.44, 2011 there is a value 2.72, etc.  For every year and for every state is a value.

My assignment is to create another data frame with 4 columns: Index, State, Year and Value

I have created a null dataframe with STATE, YEAR and VALUE

I know that I should you .tolist and .append but I am having trouble starting.  The output should look something like:

```
State Year Value

AL    2010 2.44

AL    2011 2.72
```

Each row (state) plus each year (Year) plus each value (value) should not be its' own table.

There should be a table that is 4 columns x 510 rows

How do I extract that information?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) for this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'State':'AL', 2010:2.44, 2011:2.72, 2012:3.68}, {'State':'AK', 2010:3.60, 2011:3.93, 2012:4.91}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['State'], var_name='Year', value_name='Value').sort_values(by=['State'])
```

Output:

|  | State | Year | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AK | 2010 | 3.6 |
| 3 | AK | 2011 | 3.93 |
| 5 | AK | 2012 | 4.91 |
| 0 | AL | 2010 | 2.44 |
| 2 | AL | 2011 | 2.72 |
| 4 | AL | 2012 | 3.68 |